# Laravel 5.3 class not found

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I just upgraded from laravel 5.2 to laravel 5.3
Currently I have troubles with the Mailables.

I always receive the `ReflectionException` `Class  not found`. The strange thing is that, when I try sending the mail directly (without queuing), no problems occur.

I reviewed the jobs table in my database, as I am using the database queuing driver. But that doesn't seems to be the issue.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
in Container.php line 734
at ReflectionClass->__construct('') in Container.php line 734
at Container->build('', array()) in Container.php line 629
at Container->make('', array()) in Application.php line 699
at Application->make('') in Job.php line 83
at Job->resolve('') in Job.php line 149
at Job->failed(object(ReflectionException)) in SyncQueue.php line 168
at SyncQueue->handleFailedJob(object(SyncJob), object(ReflectionException)) in SyncQueue.php line 65
at SyncQueue->handleSyncException(object(SyncJob), object(ReflectionException)) in SyncQueue.php line 46
at SyncQueue->push(object(SendQueuedMailable)) in Mailable.php line 138
at Mailable->queue(object(QueueManager)) in Mailer.php line 211
at Mailer->queue(object(OrderReceived)) in MailableMailer.php line 127
at MailableMailer->queue(object(OrderReceived)) in VisitorController.php line 302
at VisitorController->_flushToDatabase(array('firstName' => 'Jules', 'lastName' => 'test', 'email' => 'demo@gmail.com', 'subscribe' => 'true', 'printTicketsByOrganisation' => 'true', 'tickets' => array(array('priceId' => '5947ed599e6a4e19bba0d9b54cb8a471', 'price' => '15.00', 'category' => 'Standaardprijs', 'seat' => '267', 'amount' => '1'), array('priceId' => '49f91249bff343f09cf1a90b9dd5cc1d', 'price' => '5-5.00', 'category' => 'Kinderen (GRATIS)', 'seat' => '266', 'amount' => '1'))), object(Request)) in VisitorController.php line 261
at VisitorController->ajaxPersist(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VisitorController), 'ajaxPersist'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 52
at Controller->callAction('ajaxPersist', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(VisitorController), 'ajaxPersist') in Route.php line 190
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TicketsAvailable.php line 25
at TicketsAvailable->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TicketsOpen.php line 29
at TicketsOpen->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 263
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/home/jules/sites/tickets/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

My mailable class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Event;
use App\Visitor;
use App\Organisation;

class OrderReceived extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $visitor;
    private $event;
    private $organisation;
    private $bankingCode;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     * @param App\Visitor $visitor The visitor who bought the tickets
     * @param App\Event $event The event where the visitor bought tickets from
     * @param App\Organisation $organisation The organisation that hosts the event
     * @param string $bankingCode The formatted banking code the user should use for payement
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Visitor $visitor, Event $event, Organisation $organisation, $bankingCode)
    {
        $this->visitor = $visitor;
        $this->event = $event;
        $this->organisation = $organisation;
        $this->bankingCode;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.visitor.payementRequestEmail')
            ->subject(trans('messages.emailPayementRequest'))
            ->with([
            'langCode' => \App::getLocale(),
            'eventName' => $this->event->name,
            'organisationName' => $this->organisation->name,
            'name' => $this->visitor->firstName.' '.$this->visitor->lastName,
            'bankAccount' => chunk_split($this->organisation->bankAccount,4,' '),//format to ISO 13616
            'bankingCode' => $this->bankingCode,      
            'url' => $this->organisation->url,
            'color' => $this->organisation->colorAsHex,
            'ticketAmount' => $this->visitor->seats()->count(),
            'totalPrice' => $this->visitor->calculateTotalPrice(),
            'email' => $this->organisation->email,
            'userEmail' => $this->visitor->email,
            'printedByOrganisation' => $this->visitor->printTicketsByOrganisation,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And finally, the call to send the e-mail:
`Mail::to($visitor->email)->queue(new OrderReceived($visitor, $event, $event->organisation()->first(), $humanBankingCode));`

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug in Laravel?

Comment: I'm assuming you've deleted the bootstrap/cache/* files, tried composer dumpautoload and artisan clear-compiled - but it doesn't hurt to double-check. :)

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. It's the queue method that causes the exception

Answer (score 1):

After configuring the mail settings in `config/mail.php`, use the Mail class in your controller and place the below code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

or

```
use Mail;
```

Then execute the code. Its working fine for me.